# How to use ORDER BY with IN statement in cassandra query in DevCenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

Trying to use "order by" clause with IN statement of Cassandra query in DevCenter.
Unable to  PAGING OFF in DevCenter

I have table 
model_vals :

```
-----------------------------------------------
type_code         date                 item_code
-------------------------------------------------
TYPE_0           2018-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_10          2018-03-31           CREDITS  
TYPE_25          2018-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_50          2018-03-31           CREDITS 
TYPE_75          2018-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_90          2018-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_100         2018-03-31           CREDITS
MEAN             2018-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_0           2017-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_10          2017-03-31           CREDITS  
TYPE_25          2017-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_50          2017-03-31           CREDITS 
TYPE_75          2017-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_90          2017-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_100         2017-03-31           CREDITS
MEAN             2017-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_0           2016-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_10          2016-03-31           CREDITS  
TYPE_25          2016-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_50          2016-03-31           CREDITS 
TYPE_75          2016-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_90          2016-03-31           CREDITS
TYPE_100         2016-03-31           CREDITS
MEAN             2016-03-31           CREDITS
```

Trying to execute below query in DevCenter:

```
select * from model_vals
where  type='COUNTRY'
and type_code  in (
'TYPE_0',
'TYPE_10',
'TYPE_25',
'TYPE_50',
'TYPE_75',
'TYPE_90',
'TYPE_100',
'MEAN')
and item_code='CREDITS'
and date <='2018-03-31'
order by date desc;
```

1) 
Getting error as "order by" and "in" clause cant be used together.
Unable to PAGING OFF in DevCenter , how to do it ?

2)
If have to fetch the records of 2018 records with all type_code using date <='2018-03-31'. i.e. total 8 records.

If dont have '2018-03-31' records then it should get next data  8 records i.e. for all types  in 2017-03-31.

If dont have data of 2017-03-31, then it should get next data  8 records i.e. for all types  in 2016-03-31.

How can achieve this kind of results query ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorting of data happens only inside the single partition, while you're providing multiple partitions in the `IN` statement. For your use case it's better not to use multiple partition key values with `IN`, but instead execute multiple parallel request for every single value of partition key, get data, and then sort data in your application.

P.S. I recommend to get [some of the courses on DataStax Academy](http://academy.datastax.com/), like, DS220 (Data modelling).